# How did Roderick Roach know exactly how his father died?

Tags: the-ickabog

Lord Spittleworth shoots Major Roach when he fails to capture Bert. He then has the rest of Roach family arrested. Later, in the story : Roderick describes to Bert how exactly his father died  :

> 

From the way he describes it, it sounds like Roderick witnessed the incident. But how could this be  ?  The soldiers didn't obviously describe what happened because they came to arrest the Roach family .

How did Roderick know how his father died  ?

Comment: I am unable to add  the quote as I can't access  my clipboard for some reason